# Flutter _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to flutter and getting type error. I am trying to use json automated serializations.

AFTER DOING SOME TWEAKS HERE IS HOW IT LOOKS LIKE

[image]

Here is how I am trying to get the data from api

```
  Future getMyProduct() async {
     final res = await http.get('url');
     final data = json.decode(res.body);
     BaseResponse req = new BaseResponse.fromJson(data);
     return req;
  }
```

My `BaseResponse` class looks like this

```
import 'package:dynamicapp/model/model.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'response.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class BaseResponse extends Object {
    final int id;

final int sellingPrice;
final int totalStock;
final String productName;
final String productDesc;
final List<Image> images;

BaseResponse(this.id, this.sellingPrice, this.totalStock, this.productName,
    this.productDesc, this.images);

factory BaseResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BaseResponseFromJson(json);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BaseResponseToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
 class Image extends Object {
    final int id;
    final String image;
//  final int product_id;

   Image(this.id, this.image);
factory Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ImageFromJson(json);
   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ImageToJson(this);
}
```

Could anyone please help me with this. I am stuck here. Have been trying different methods but none working. Thank you.

Comment: change `json.decode` to `jsonDecode` . Look this: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: It gives same error. I followed exactly like documentations. Still same error

Comment: try change `final data` to `final Map data` to explicit the return type of  `jsonDecode`

Comment: It gives the same error 
`final Map data = jsonDecode(res.body);
     var p = BaseResponse.fromJson(data);`

How can I convert the `BaseResponse.fromJson(data)` into a list instead of a map?

Comment: OK I got the problem. It returns an array of items and in the BaseResponse call I have Object. So if I write `BaseResponse.fromJson(jsonresponse[0]);` it works with 0 index. But how can I make a list of array?

Comment: So, if `data` is a `List<dynamic>`, then `data.map(someFunc).toList()` will take each element of `data` pass it to `someFunc` and form it back into a list of the return type of `someFunc` (which you will presumably want to be `BaseResponse`). Which tells you that `someFunc` needs to be a function that takes `dynamic` and returns `BaseResponse`. It doesn't have to do much more than call `BaseResponse.fromJson`.

Comment: @RichardHeap would you please write this a clean answer with some code please? It's gone over my brain :( Your help would be nice. Thank you

Comment: I think I did it like this 

`var d = jsonresponse.map((el) => BaseResponse.fromJson(el)).toList();
     for(var k in d){
         print(k.productName);
     }`

This is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `data` is a `List<dynamic>`, then `data.map(someFunc).toList()` will take each element of data pass it to `someFunc` and form it back into a list of the return type of `someFunc` (which you will presumably want to be `BaseResponse`). Which tells you that `someFunc` needs to be a function that takes `dynamic` and returns `BaseResponse`.

You'd want to write something like this:

```
  final data = json.decode(res.body);
  List<BaseResponse> responses =
      data.map((j) => BaseResponse.fromJson(j)).toList();
```

Comment: could you help me on this issue? `https://stackoverflow.com/q/56524623/1830228` thanks